# Remove unneeded 'system apps', and notifications (tool)

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, 4.2-jelly-bean, google-apps

There does appear to be cumbersome methods: (*that you may not know of ..*)

**(1.)** Goto: Settings > Applications Manager

For each application, un-tick 'Show notifications', press 'Ok'.

( repeat 100 times )

**(2.)** Goto: Settings > Applications Manager > (scroll to right) (select ALL)

For each SYSTEM application (you don't want, eg. ***Google+***):

- un-tick 'Show notifications', press 'Ok'
- click 'Force Stop', wait .., click 'Ok'
- click 'Remove Updates', wait .., click 'Ok'
- click 'Disable', wait .., click 'Ok'  (option not visible, until updates removed)

( repeat as needed, for: Chat On, Group Play, Hang Outs (Talk), You Tube, Game Hub, WiFi Direct + WiFi Direct Share )

---

***My real question ..***

Is there a **tool** to automate this? (global disable-notifications, simple un-tick for system 'bloatware')

> Why is this not in **Google Play** (from desktop browser)? *More of a philosophical question.*
>
> What portion of (unwanted) data traffic is caused by this 'bloatware'?

Answer (score 1):

As WiKi says, such a tool would require root on your phone. For security reasons, only system apps can enable and disable notifications for an app, only system apps can force-stop other apps, and only system apps can disable other apps. You really wouldn't want every app on your phone to be able to turn on notifications for itself and disable the Settings app so you can't turn them off again.

If you want to disable most of your system apps, it sounds like it might be better for you to replace the OS with a [custom-rom](/questions/tagged/custom-rom). The tag wiki for that page will give you some hints to get started. Be warned before you decide: you do need to unlock the bootloader to achieve this, and you should take a backup first as it's an advanced procedure: people do manage to brick their phones this way.

As a quick note: most of the apps you list are Samsung's apps. Samsung are known for shipping particularly bloat-heavy software, so you may find it easier to buy a phone from a different manufacturer next time. Nexus phones in particular run a very minimal Android: that's their main selling point.

Answer (score -3):

You need to root your phone for this.

Comment: Can you provide a better explanation? *I can do the cumbersome method, and don't need to 'root' the phone.* **What can I do, after I 'root' my phone?**